# Wcf not saving changes

Tags: database, entity-framework, wcf

I created a project to expose some actions of a MVC app to a Winforms app one of these actions must save a new visitor to the database, i have a MVC project that has a reference to a local service(using EF6) project that writes on the database thast OK!, but when i create the WCF project to use the service project and call the write method, this complete ok with no errors but doesn´t write the data.

Here is the code of my WCF

```
public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(VisitanteComposite item)
    {
        try
        {
            var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _visitanteServicio.Create(Mapper.Map<Visitante>(item)));
            await myTask;
            return myTask.IsCompleted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

These is the generic create Method

```
    public virtual void Create(T item)
    {
        try
        {
            Repositorio.Add(item);
            UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //_logger.Debug(item.GetType() + " Error al crear:  " + ex.Message);
            throw new ServiceException("Ocurrio un error al crear el item", ex);
        }
    }
```

These is the repository method

```
 public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
```

I rewrite the WCF to this and work

```
public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(VisitanteComposite item)
    {
        try
        {
            var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var db = new ModelContainer())
                {
                    var visitante = new Visitante
                    {
                        Apellido = item.Apellido,
                        Nombre = item.Nombre,
                        TipoDocumentoId = item.TipoDocumentoId,
                        NumeroDocumento = item.NumeroDocumento
                    };
                    AplicarFiltros(visitante);
                    db.Set<Visitante>().Add(visitante);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            });
            await myTask;

            return myTask.IsCompleted;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but i want to reuse the previous methods

Comment: You are only showing that the "Create" method was called, but not showing its contents. Maybe your problem is inside this method. When you edit the question, please, try to improve the question and add more info about your issue.

Comment: Also, you don't need to say: "i´m new to WCF", "the client wants that dont know why", "can somebody help me!" and "Sorry for my english i know is not so god".

Comment: It is clear now. So, if you change the `UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();` for `DbContext.SaveChanges();`, in the `Create()` method, will it work? Or maybe you should create a method like `Repositorio.SaveChanges()` and it will make the call `DbContext.SaveChanges();`

Comment: The UnitOfWork.SaveChanges() method has the DbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: And the MVC Project uses the create method and has no problems, only if i use the WCF project is the problem

Comment: Are you looking for data in the right place? Check your connection string.

Comment: The connection string is the same that uses the MVC app